# How to bind columns and rename at the same time?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to save residuals from a linear model to a dataframe. I was trying to do it with the line of code (note that this was supposed to go inside a loop):

```
resi <- NULL 
resi <- cbind(resi, colnames(dados[1])=residuals(m))
```

Here I intended to save the residuals vector from my model **m** under the same column name from the **dados** object (which is basicaly a date), but I get the error:

> Error: unexpected '=' in "resi <- cbind(resi, colnames(dados[1])="

Comment: It is better to avoid `=` in a loop, try  `<-`

Comment: Have a look at `setNames()`

Answer (score 1):

You want `` `colnames <- ()` ``.

```
cbind(d, `colnames<-`(d, letters[1:4]))
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 a b c  d
# 1  1  4  7 10 1 4 7 10
# 2  2  5  8 11 2 5 8 11
# 3  3  6  9 12 3 6 9 12
```

It's similar to `setNames()` but also compatible with matrices.

---

*Toydata*

```
d <- data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this in `tibble`

```
library(tibble)
tibble(resi, !!colnames(dados)[1] :=residuals(m))
```